# Prevent HTML Tidy from stripping PHP

Tags: html, htmltidy

I have gone through the docs but am not seeing how I can prevent tidy from stripping my PHP. My config is as follows:

```css
anchor-as-name: no
doctype: omit
drop-empty-paras: no
fix-uri: no
literal-attributes: yes
merge-divs: no
merge-spans: no
numeric-entities: no
preserve-entities: yes
quote-ampersand: no
quote-marks: no
show-body-only: yes
indent: auto
indent-spaces: 4
tab-size: 4
wrap: 0
wrap-asp: no
wrap-jste: no
wrap-php: no
wrap-sections: no
tidy-mark: no
new-blocklevel-tags: article,aside,command,canvas,dialog,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section,summary,meter 
new-inline-tags: video,audio,canvas,ruby,rt,rp,time,meter,progress,datalist,keygen,mark,output,source,wbr
force-output: yes
quiet: yes
show-warnings: yes
```

Comment: maybe the php will save a cache html file, then tidy will clean that.

Comment: I'm not following. Can you clarify?

Comment: The PHP will generate the HTML and then save it to an html file. PHP tidy will use the generated html file

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear there is a way to use tidy in php like this. (Even as of php 5.5)
After trying lots of variations including stuff which should be valid SGML like `<script language="php">` and `<!-- <?php echo 1; ?> !-->`
It appears its actively stripping out php tags.

The tidy library in php is most often used as an output filter; something that takes all the output of your page before its sent to the browser and fixes it.
The most basic example of this is right out of the [php manual.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php)

```
<?php
//start the output buffer to capture all page output.
ob_start();
?>
<html>a html document
     <div><?php echo 'do your thing here' ?></div>
</html>
<?php
//get the contents of the output buffer.
$html = ob_get_clean();

// configure tidy
$config = array(
           'indent'         => true,
           'output-xhtml'   => true,
           'wrap'           => 200);
//tidy the html
$tidy = new tidy;
$tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
// Output the clean html.
echo $tidy;
```